# Simulation "docker build -f" with ansible module "docker_image"

Tags: docker, ansible, docker-image

While I build docker image and I want to add the instruction "COPY" in Dockerfile with a directory which is outside of current build directory(place where Dockerfile is placed) - I'm using something like this:

> docker build -f centos6-fresh/Dockerfile -t test/c6-fresh .

Now I want to do provisioning containers and building docker images through ansible. 
Of course I'm able to do it with shell, command or raw modules, but I saw special module for Docker.

So I've used module "docker_image"

```
- name: Build test image
       docker_image:
           path: /docker/build_env/test
           name: test_build
           tag: v0
```

And certainly I've got the error.

**Is there any option, to set from which directory, building process must be started?**

*UPD*
The example of case where I need these manipulations:

I have management node(my laptop) with ansible and Docker host with containers. Ansible dir is provisioning with git to Docker server.

Usually  I build an image in the directory build_env on the Docker host:

```
[root@docker build_env]# ls -1
ansible
centos6-fresh
centos7-fresh
debian8-fresh
templates
test
```

So after run "git pull" in ansible directory, I run something like

> docker build -f centos6-fresh/Dockerfile -t test/c6-fresh .

Dockerfile consists:

> COPY ansible /etc/ansible

As we now, docker prevents to use something like "COPY ../ansible" in the COPY or ADD options.

Comment: of course as a variant I can pull ansible dir into the build directory and after the building an image  I can run cleanup, but it's a dirty hook I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docker_image documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/docker_image_module.html), there is a `dockerfile` option that is an exact analog to the `-f` command line option.  So you would just need:

```
- name: Build test image
  docker_image:
    path: /docker/build_env/
    name: test_build
    tag: v0
    dockerfile: centos6-fresh/Dockerfile
```

Comment: You're right! Thanks a lot.
I saw it but didn't try because I didn't  understand what it invented for.